# Regular expression help in PHP

Tags: php, regex, content-management-system

I have a block of text where I need yo find bits of text like:
{slider:1}
{video-alt:10}

I have this bit of code

```
$regex = '/{[ ]*(slider)|(slider-alt)|(video)[ ]*:[0-9]+[ ]*}/';
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all( $regex, $row->content, $matches );
```

But the array returned is all messed up...

Array output:

```
Array ( [0] => {slider [1] => {slider [2] => video:2} )
Array ( [0] => slider [1] => slider [2] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => video )
```

For the input:

```
{slider:6}
{slider-alt:2}
{video:2}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp is messy.

```
$regex = '/{ *(slider|slider-alt|video) *:\d+ *}/';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all( $regex, $row->content, $matches );
```

Comment: Thanks but this still does do it... I've update the anwser with the result of your changes.

Comment: Where is your updated answer? `var_dump($matches[0]);` gives `array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "{slider:6}" [1]=> string(14) "{slider-alt:2}" [2]=> string(9) "{video:2}" }`

Comment: Isn't the first array what you need? ;)